# Derivation of Feynman Rules for a $\frac{1}{\phi}$ potential

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, potential, feynman-diagrams

The question is more mathematical in nature. If one had a potential $V(\phi) = \frac{\lambda}{\phi}$, where $\lambda$ is a constant, then how does one derive the Feynman rules for this scalar field's Lagrangian (assuming one is given the usual kinetic term)? Does one expand this as a Taylor series around some minimum and then find the rules?

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/251515/84967

Comment: The theory might be ill-defined in several ways... I assume you have considered Schwinger's formal wisecrack: $1/\phi=\int_0^\infty ds \exp (-s\phi) ~$?

Comment: @gj255 This is actually something another person I asked wondered too. I though that if you restricted the field to be a continuous function from some compact interval, assuming that you are working in $1+0$ dimensions, then you know that the field must take a minimum value somewhere. Is it possible to expand it about a minimum of that sort. I would suppose not, since you need an open set to define analyticity of any sort. Of course, you can consider an open interval around the point of minimum, assuming that the minimum is not achieved on the boundary and then expand it. Does that work?

Comment: @Cynthia'sLight If you restricted your field to lie in some closed interval of $\mathbb{R}$ then yes, by standard theorems of analysis, you could find a power series expansion of the potential about one of the boundary points (although I don't know that the dimensionality of spacetime is relevant here?). This said, I can't quite see how such a theory (with $\phi$ restricted in this way) would be physically motivated.