# Negative powers of fields in a QFT Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, action

I have a Lagrangian that it have a term $\frac{1}{h}Tr(M^2)$ where $M$ is a  3*3  matrix and scalar field $h$ is one dimension. Is it correct to have such field with negative power in a Lagrangian?

Comment: Presumably of interest: see the last paragraph in QMechanic's answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/251515/84967).

Comment: define "correct" please.

Comment: What's the rest of the Lagrangian?

Comment: @RhoPhi +1 ....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is ok (if the Action is real-valued and has Basic invariances like Lorentz invariance).

Note that you can do the Substitution $u = \frac{1}{h}$ and the new $u$ field appears linear in the Action. What will Change is the measure factor in the path integral

$\mathcal{D}[u] = - \frac{1}{h^2}\mathcal{D}[h] = -u^2 \mathcal{D}[h]$.

When computing the path integral, there will appear e.g. Gamma functions.

Comment: .Many Thanks. If this Lagrangian is  defined in QCD,again is it ok?Is there any problem due to renormalization?

Comment: define "ok" please.

Comment: I mean  what about the case that  this Lagrangian is defined in QCD.  Is  there any problem because of the renormalization?